# Apex 5 or 18 - Element placement (New Row: No, New Column No)

Tags: oracle-apex

need your help to place a field right after another one.

In the old Apex I was selecting New Row: No and New Column: No IN this case all was fine and it was beautifully placed right after previous element.

[image]

In this situation Unk check box is a new element that is placed right after Blood Pressure systolic and diastolic fields. So nicely placed 3 fields what give a nice rendering on the page.

In Apex 5 and 18 I can not do this at all , or I am getting the field below the element or I have to use Next Column:Yes and can not use labels and I do not understand why it is so ugly

[image]

Please help me: Is there a way to obtain the exact output I was getting before.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this has got anything to do with the layout property values of the page items.

The fact that the two text fields and the check box are highlighted with in one region in the layout tells me that its all listed under one field (page item) and not under multiple page elements. Make sure to check the page item attributes of Blood Pressure to see how this has been implemented. You could also view them by inspecting (CTRL+SHIFT+I) the fields in the browser itself. Once you figure that out, it should not be too difficult to replicate that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I am using Oracle APEX, in Apex 4.2 I was using the Theme 26 Productivity, and in that Theme i have 2 element and for the second one I put No new Row no new Column. Working as a charm. With new Apex 5 it is a total disaster. Or elements are far away apart or second element is below the first one :(

Answer (score 1):

I agree - annoying disaster. It worked so well in 4.2 ...

Here's what I do; see if it helps.

- I set "new row: no"
- Then I click the "Show layout columns" button (at the bottom of the page I ran) so that I can see those "pink and white" stripes which show columns.
- Return back to developer, select the item that is supposed to be placed on the right and modify its properties:

  - column (you have to number them)
  - pay attention to "columns span" and "label column span" properties because - if you don't do that carefully, you'll keep getting errors, such as *you can't set it that way because item takes 3 columns in total, while you'd want to set label to span 4 columns* and similar
- run the page; see if it makes sense. If not, change properties and run it again. And again, and again ...

Shortly, you *can* get what you want, but it takes both your time and your nerves. I have no idea why those good & nice Apex developers "*improved*" this simple setting that way ...

Comment: Hi. At list one more person is with me on this one. Looks like no one else is really interested how your app looks. All are just using by default design (each field on new row). Thanks for the advise, and I already doing this. The biggest problem is that if you go from one screen resolution to another, the elements are getting some times too far apart, or vices-versa the labels are get crumpled. Very annoying! I do not understand why  No new Row no new Column can result in opposite, bringing the element below (winch is actually new row) :(

Comment: Obviously, not every higher version means an improvement. Hopefully, they'll fix it some day.

Comment: While I find the odd problem, I don't think I ever have as much hassle as what seems to be desribed here. I'm relatively happy with use of new row/column span/label span/stretching of items, and I'm on 5.1

Comment: I'm happy that you're happy, @Scott. But I'm unhappy with what "New row/column" does in this version (I'm on 5.1 as well).

Comment: I must say when 'new column' is No, I am sometimes perplexed at the behaviour. I'm *mostly* happy ;p